# Teysa, Orzhov Scion sacrificing one creature multiple times to exhile

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a rules question for you all. I run [Teysa, Orzhov Scion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teysa%2C%20Orzhov%20Scion) and many black/white creatures in my decks, and I'm wondering if I can sacrifice a black/white creature for her exile ability, and then sacrifice the white spirit token that I get for having a black creature go to the graveyard towards that same instance of her exile ability.

If not, do I have to sacrifice all of the creatures at the same time, or can I, for example, sacrifice two, play a third, and then sacrifice that one?

Answer (score 2):

The cost must be payed all at once.

The triggered ability that provides the Spirit token would not be placed on the stack, much less resolve, before you finish activating the ability. This happens the next time a player would get priority.

As such, you will not have a Spirit token to sacrifice before you finish activating the ability, which means you won't have a Spirit token to sacrifice to activate the ability, which means you are unable to activate the ability.

Answer (score 1):

All costs have to be paid for the ability to go on the stack. In this case, you have to sacrifice all 3 creatures at the same time to get the exile.